# Sheldon Cooper has a Master of Arts degree?

Tags: dialogue, the-big-bang-theory

Both [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Bang_Theory#Main_cast) and [The Big Bang Theory Wiki](http://bigbangtheory.wikia.com/wiki/Sheldon_Cooper) say that Sheldon Cooper of the Big Bang Theory has a Master of Arts degree.  They both cite "The Love Car Displacement" episode as the source for that.  But I can't find any mention of that in [the episode's script](http://bigbangtrans.wordpress.com/series-4-episode-13-the-love-car-displacement/).

Does Sheldon really have a Master of Arts degree?  That seems very strange for someone who has devoted his entire life to science, and who has such a strong disdain for anything non-science related (and even certain sciences like geology).  If he does have a M.A., what field is it in?

Comment: Oxford and Cambridge call (almost all) their undergraduate degrees Bachelor of Arts; presumably, other universities name their degrees similarly. The situation is analogous to Sheldon being a Doctor of Philosophy, despite not having studied philosophy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sheldon does say it, but he uses the initialism when introducing himself at the start of the lecture they are presenting:

> Good morning and welcome to Science and Society. I’m Dr. Sheldon Cooper, BS, MS, **MA**, PhD, and ScD. OMG, right? Perhaps that joke was a little too hippie-dippy for this crowd. All right then, we’ll begin with opening remarks. Miss Rostenkowski, would you like to start us off by discussing your assessment of science’s responsibility to society?

[As Wikipedia notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_Arts), this is a common shorthand for Master of Arts:

> A Master of Arts (M.A., MA, A.M., or AM) from the Latin Magister Artium, is a type of Master's degree awarded by universities in many countries.

Comment: Ah, I searched for "Master", "degree", "M.A.", but not "MA".  I take it the show has never mentioned what field it's in?

Comment: @pacoverflow As I recall he hasn't, but he does know a lot of languages, so it's possible the degree is one of those as language degrees are usually Arts. Though it's equally possible that it's just a throwaway line for the 'joke'.

Comment: FWIW "of arts" doesn't mean that the field of the degree is an artistic one. A number of colleges label all their degrees Bachelor of Arts, even for those majoring in a science. I suppose the same could hold for master's degrees.

Comment: I know of at least one university that had a bug in its undergraduate program that allowed someone to do one course of study, and get both a BS and BA off the credits (they where transitioning from using BA for science degrees to a BS for science degrees).  One could imagine Sheldon spotting a similar technical rules, exploiting them, and getting an extra degree as a MA without actually getting an MA.

Comment: "One could imagine Sheldon spotting a similar technical rules, exploiting them, and getting an extra degree as a MA without actually getting an MA. – Yakk 19 hours ago". That would be intellectually dishonest, as Sheldon has expressed a disinterest in, in 'The Extract Obliteration'. Although, that episode is later and this show has a significant amount of plot holes...