# Is it known in which fields Sheldon Cooper's two doctorates and one master's degree are?

Tags: the-big-bang-theory

In *The Big Bang Theory* it is mentioned that Sheldon Cooper has two doctorates and a master's degree.

Except for the one in physics, is it known in which fields his other two degrees are?

Comment: Sheldon has a PhD in physics and a Sc.D which is a Doctor of Science I believe and also an MA which is master of arts degree, I'm on my phone so hopefully someone can answer fully with links, quotes etc

Comment: See also https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/26847/sheldon-cooper-has-a-master-of-arts-degree [which doesn't answer this, but is related]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the episode "The Love Car Displacement" (S4E13) Sheldon says

> I'm Doctor Sheldon Cooper, B.S. (Bachelor of Science), M.S. (Master of Science), M.A. (Master of Arts), Ph.D. (Doctor of Philosophy) and Sc.D. (Doctor of Science). OMG (Oh My God), right?

[Source: fandom.com](https://bigbangtheory.fandom.com/wiki/The_Love_Car_Displacement) / [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B6CIcoot1sM)

His research fields are as follows:

1. Theoretical Nuclear and Particle Physics – Superstrings and Quantum Gravity, Particle Cosmology, Collider Phenomenology, Superheavy Elements
2. Theoretical Cosmology – Dark Matter, Spacetime Analogue, Penrose Conjecture
3. Theoretical Condensed Matter Physics – Bose-Einstein Condensates, Superfluids, Graphene Quasiparticles, Topological Insulators, Thermodynamic Fluctuations, Polymer Degradation
4. Theoretical Plasma Physics – Turbulent Diffusion in Fusion Devices
5. Philosophy of Physics – Quantum Measurement Problem

Source: [Fandom](https://bigbangtheory.fandom.com/wiki/User_blog:Sheldon_Cooper_PhD/The_Grasshopper_Experiment)

There aren't any later mentions of further degrees, but he and Amy also get awarded the Nobel Prize by the end of the series.

So you can assume that he got all his degrees in physics.

Comment: *So you can assume that he got all his degrees in physics.* But he has a MA as well. That cannot be related to Physics, right?

Comment: @Sandun - Wrong - https://physics.berkeley.edu/academics/graduate-degree/ma-degree